# Design pattern to process different messages based on message type

Tags: design-patterns, lambda, java-8

I need to process notification messages that gets pushed to my application. where the messages contain notification types like `catalog_purchased, catalog_expired, catalog_denied` etc. and In future new set of notification types would be added as well.
What would be a good Design Pattern (and any Java 8 features) to process all these messages based on Notification types instead of just using if-else blocks?

```
public class CustomMessage(){
  private String messageType;
  private Message message;
}
public void pushedMessage(CustomMessage message){
   //*TO-DO* need to implement code that handles one message at a time
}
```

Comment: EventBus of some kind. Guava provides a nice one

Comment: @Eugene Do you think EventBus is needed if I had to process just one message at a time?

Comment: why not say that in the question and not the comments? This changes that problem quite a lot, since now you need a queue... But IIRC guava's EventBus will process elements sequentially anyway.

Comment: I modified my question, I already have a queue. I'm only trying to decouple the message processing logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a map with message type as key and processing logic as value

```
public static Map<String, Processor> PROCESSORS_MAP = Map.of(
    "catalog_purchased", customMsg -> System.out.println("catalog_purchased: " + customMsg),
    "catalog_expired", customMsg -> System.out.println("catalog_expired: " + customMsg),
    "catalog_denied", customMsg -> System.out.println("catalog_denied: " + customMsg)
);
```

where `Processor` is a functional interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Processor {
    void process(CustomMessage msg);
}
```

and use it as follows

```
PROCESSORS_MAP.get(customMessage.getMessageType()).process(customMessage);
```

Of course if logic for processing a message is pretty big you should create a class that implements `Processor` instead of using lambda.

Comment: Yes, the logic would be big to process the message, I figured I could just use different methods with same arguments rather than classes. Is there any name for this kind of pattern?

Comment: @dreambigcoder I don't think that's a pattern, more like procedural programming with lots of if. If your concern is too much code in lambda then you can create implementations `Map.of( "catalog_purchased", new CatalogPurchasedProcessor());` and it's easier to UT this way, also you can mark these as Spring beans and use DI

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion best design pattern is Factory pattern. since client doesn't know which service or method would be call based on data entry. I just provided a sample although you can use java 8 features. [**there is a good sample**](https://medium.com/@mhd.durrah/factory-pattern-the-dynamic-way-with-java-8-3ca5ab48a9cf).

so first of all define an interface:

```
public interface MessageProcess {

  public void pushedMessage(CustomMessage message); 

  public String messageType();

}
```

and suppose you would have some process service like these:

```
public class ServiceA implements MessageProcess{

  @Override
  public void pushedMessage(CustomMessage message) {

  }

  @Override
  public String messageType() {
      return "messageType1";
  }
}
```

and also:

```
public class ServiceB implements MessageProcess {

  @Override
  public void pushedMessage(CustomMessage message) {
      System.out.println("pushed message by serviceB: " + message.toString());
  }

  @Override
  public String messageType() {
      return "messageType2";
  }
}
```

now you can create a Factory class which identify specify service based on message type.

```
public class MessageFactory {

  public MessageProcess getByType(String messageType) {
     if (messageType.equals("messageType1"))
         return new ServiceA();
     else if (messageType.equals("messageType2"))
         return new ServiceB();
     return null;
  }
}
```

and now we use it such as this:

```
 public class MessageProcessTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     MessageFactory messageFactory = new MessageFactory();

      messageFactory.getByType("messageType2").pushedMessage(new CustomMessage("catalog1"));
  }
}
```